# How can we remove close_wait state of the socket without restarting the server?

Tags: sockets, visual-c++, wait

We have written an application in which client-server communication is used with the IOCP concept.

Client connects to the server through wireless access points.

When temporary disconnection happens in the network, this can lead a CLOSE_WAIT state.This could indicate that the
client properly closed the connection. But the server still has its socket open.
If there are too many instances of the port (to which the server and client were talking) were in CLOSE_WAIT state then at the highest peak ,server stop functioning thus rejecting the connection.That is totally frustrating.In this case, user has to restart the server to wipe out all the close_wait state by clearing the memory.When server restart,client again try to connect to the server.Server calls accept command again,But before accepting a new connection ,previous connection should be closed at server side,How can we do that ?

How can we remove close_wait state of the socket without restarting the server ?

Is there any alternate way to avoid server restart ?

We also came to know that,If all of the available ephemeral  ports are allocated to client applications then the
client experiences a condition known as TCP/IP port exhaustion. When TCP/IP port exhaustion occurs, client port
reservations cannot be made and errors will occur in client applications that attempt to connect to a server via TCP/IP sockets.
if this is happening then we need to increase the upper range of ephemeral ports that are dynamically allocated to client TCP/IP socket connections.

Reference :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560610%28v=bts.10%29.aspx

Let us know if this alternate way is useful or not ?

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Amey

Answer (score 0):

Fix the server code.

The server should be reading with a timeout, and if the timeout expires it should close the socket.

Comment: Can you please give detail explanation ?

Comment: What details are missing? I could comment on your code, if you had posted any, but I don't see what else I can say other than what I've said above.